# is "Empty reply from server" a deliberate reply, or a default one from the TCP/IP stack?

Tags: networking, ip, tcp, tcpip

I have a device whose port `80` is open and I was wondering what is behind:

```
~ # curl -v http://192.168.10.253                                                                              root@srv
* Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.10.253/
*   Trying 192.168.10.253...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.10.253 (192.168.10.253) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.10.253
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.10.253 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

In order to better understand the exchange, I had a look at the packets:

```
~ # tcpdump -vvv -nn host 192.168.10.253 and port 80                                                           root@srv
tcpdump: listening on int0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:02:55.353246 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9407, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.10.2.43894 > 192.168.10.253.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x967e (incorrect -> 0x0967), seq 2730220431, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1779439926 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:02:55.355251 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 1565, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    192.168.10.253.80 > 192.168.10.2.43894: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdbda (correct), seq 100303, ack 2730220432, win 24576, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 1], length 0
12:02:55.355270 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9408, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.2.43894 > 192.168.10.253.80: Flags [.], cksum 0x966a (incorrect -> 0x65aa), seq 1, ack 1, win 502, length 0
12:02:55.355326 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9409, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 118)
    192.168.10.2.43894 > 192.168.10.253.80: Flags [P.], cksum 0x96b8 (incorrect -> 0xeaeb), seq 1:79, ack 1, win 502, length 78: HTTP, length: 78
        GET / HTTP/1.1
        Host: 192.168.10.253
        User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
        Accept: */*

12:02:55.358822 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 1566, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.253.80 > 192.168.10.2.43894: Flags [F.], cksum 0x3778 (correct), seq 1, ack 79, win 12249, length 0
12:02:55.358982 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9410, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.2.43894 > 192.168.10.253.80: Flags [F.], cksum 0x966a (incorrect -> 0x655a), seq 79, ack 2, win 502, length 0
12:02:55.362046 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 1567, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.253.80 > 192.168.10.2.43894: Flags [.], cksum 0x3778 (correct), seq 2, ack 80, win 12248, length 0
```

The beginning is the handshake, followed by `192.168.10.2` sending the HTTP payload. The answer are the last lines above

```
12:02:55.358822 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 1566, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.253.80 > 192.168.10.2.43894: Flags [F.], cksum 0x3778 (correct), seq 1, ack 79, win 12249, length 0
12:02:55.358982 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9410, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.2.43894 > 192.168.10.253.80: Flags [F.], cksum 0x966a (incorrect -> 0x655a), seq 79, ack 2, win 502, length 0
12:02:55.362046 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 1567, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.10.253.80 > 192.168.10.2.43894: Flags [.], cksum 0x3778 (correct), seq 2, ack 80, win 12248, length 0
```

What does the `FIN` exactly mean? Is this a **deliberate** answer from the device, or a generic answer from the TCP/IP stack because "something went wrong" during the exchange?

Answer (score 0):

It could easily be either, or even both at the same time.

*Usually* FIN indicates a normal end of connection initiated by the application, i.e. the HTTP server process deliberately used close() or shutdown() on the TCP socket. Nothing went wrong as far as the transport layer is concerned, even if cURL recognizes this as an issue at application layer.

The same FIN *can* also be sent when the process crashes and the OS closes leftover connections on its behalf. There is no way for you to distinguish the two cases, because the server's TCP isn't told about the difference either.

Keep in mind that TCP doesn't deal with requests and replies. It only provides flat, continuous data streams, and it's up to the application to give them any structure. Even if there was a failure in the application, those details are usually invisible to TCP – e.g. after a crash, automated exception handling will result in the connections being deliberately closed as you're seeing here.